# Python find and keep patterns in a list and replace others

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a code to extract patterns from a each list in a list of lists. I search for patterns with specified lengths, such as 'B-' followed by 'I-'. For example, I want to keep patterns with lengths of two and replace others with a specified string from the following list:

```
list = ['O', 'B-', 'I-', 'I-', 'O', 'B-', 'I-', 'B-']
```

Expected output should be as follows:

```
expected_list_2 = ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-', 'I-', 'O']
```

As can be seen only length of two pattern 'B-', 'I-' is kept and others changed with 'O' label.

If I want to keep patterns with lengths of three, the output should be as follows:

```
expected_list_3 = ['O', 'B-', 'I-', 'I-', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
```

Considering each elements of my list of lists includes such kind of lists and I try to implement this task for each list, I asked for, is there any efficient or tricky way to do this instead of defining some if-else conditions and looping over the each element?

Comment: Why wasn't the first occurence of `'B-', 'I-'` in *list* kept?

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny It is not kept because its length is three since the pattern is ['B-', 'I-', 'I-'], and I want to keep the patterns with exactly length of two. You may consider the patterns as blocks with starting 'B-' and following all 'I-'s if exist.

Comment: So are all strings one of those three? Or how does your data look in general?

Comment: @KellyBundy you may think that I'm working on Named Entity Recognition task with IOB2 tagging. Thus, each entity may include many tokens. Actually, each list is a sentence, and each element of that list is a token label in my data. For example `['New', 'York', 'City']` is the pattern `['B-', 'I-', 'I-']`, and I count this as a length of three pattern. If I want to keep length of two patterns I should omit the `['B-', 'I-', 'I-']` because of its length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution should (please test with more relevant cases before deploying to production) find all positions of *pattern 'B-', n-1 x 'I-'* in a `list`. I extended the example *list1* to cover more cases, like *pattern* at start and end of the list and consecutive *patterns*.

```py
list1 = ['B-', 'I-', 'I-', 'O', 'B-', 'I-', 'I-', 'B-', 'I-', 'B-', 'I-', 'O', 'B-', 'I-', 'I-']
#n = 2:                                            ^^^^^^^^^   ^^^^^^^^^
#n = 3:  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

def find_pattern(list1, n):
    pattern = ['B-'] + ['I-'] * (n-1)
    first = pattern[0]
    
    # find starting indices of matching patterns
    idx = [e for e, i in enumerate(list1[:-n+1 or None])
             if i == first                   # optimization for long pattern
            and list1[e:e+n] == pattern
            and list1[e+n:e+n+1] != ['I-']]

    # insert pattern at those indices
    res = ['O'] * len(list1)
    for i in idx:
        res[i:i+n] = pattern 
    return res

print(find_pattern(list1, 2))
print(find_pattern(list1, 3))
```

Output

```
['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-', 'I-', 'B-', 'I-', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O']
['B-', 'I-', 'I-', 'O', 'B-', 'I-', 'I-', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'B-', 'I-', 'I-']
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I checked it with several conditions and it worked well, I also improve the function to support n=1 cases with a simple if else check, however I couldn't edit because of my reputation.

Comment: I updated the solution to work with `n=1`.

Comment: `list1[:-n+1 or None]` to compensade for different slicing behaviour of non negative slices.